# CRC32 check during File Upload to S3 bucket using multer

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, multer-s3

Got to do a crc32 checksum for a uploaded file before saving to s3 disk.
I am using multer and multer-s3 to upload a file to s3 which was easy to achive.
Here In middle trying to do a crc32 check during file upload. Which was partially completed The below code does the job of crc32 check perfectly but the uploaded file is not having all the chunks.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");
const { crc32 } = require('crc');

AWS.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: AWS_XXXXXX_SecretAccessKey,
  accessKeyId: AWS_XXXXXX_AccessKeyID,
  //region: 'us-east-1'
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

var upload = multer({
  limits: { fileSize: 100000 },
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: constants.AWS_Cred.bucketName,
    /* metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
        //tried moving stream logic here still no success
      }, */
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      console.log("KEY");
      var buffer = new Buffer.alloc(0);
      // const b = file.stream.pipe( new PassThrough());  -- tried to clone a stream here still failed
      file.stream.on("data", function(data) {
        buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, data]);
      }); 
      file.stream.on('end', function() {
        let fileCRCCheckSum = crc32(buffer).toString(16);
        console.log(fileCRCCheckSum);
      });
      cb(null, constants.Firmware_Saved_Location + file.originalname); 
    },
  }),
});



Router
router.post(
  "/uploadSong",
  upload.single("files"),
  uploadController.DoesSomeDBEntriesHere
);
```

Will Take care of Controller which just saves other Entries to Db.
Happy to Hear Any Suggestions.